# Problem displaying an expandable list android studio java

Tags: java, android, json, multithreading

I have made a page allowing to see tools arranged in classes and subclasses (3rd floor).
The tools database is on a server, and I receive the data as JSON.

Everything was working fine until I added a number of tools (and therefore classes)
My tools appear several times without reason in classes that are not the right ones.
I checked the JSON, no problem.
Here are screenshots of the problem and the code that allows me to retrieve the data and send it to my adapter.
Thanks for your help.

- [Random display problem image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TM6Y2.png)
- [Random display problem image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXS0p.png)
- [Random display problem image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVjDZ.png)

```java
ArrayList<String> famille1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> typeliste = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>>>> ma = new HashMap<>();
ArrayList<String> materiauliste = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>>>> materielsItemList = new HashMap<>();
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FetchData fetchData = new FetchData("http://" + adresseIp.getAdresseIP() + "/jsonmateriels.php");
        if (fetchData.startFetch()) {
            if (fetchData.onComplete()) {
                String json = fetchData.getResult();
                        try {
                            HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>>> typeItemList = new HashMap<>();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                            JSONArray jsonArrayOutils = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Outils");
                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayOutils.length(); j++) {
                                HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>>> typeItemList1 = new HashMap<>();
                                JSONObject fam = jsonArrayOutils.getJSONObject(j);
                                String famille = fam.names().getString(0);//permet d'avoir les choses contenu dans la classe soudeurs
                                JSONArray jsonArrayFamille = fam.getJSONArray(famille);//permet de récupérer le suivant
                                famille1.add(famille);
                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayFamille.length(); i++) {
                                    HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>> matItemList = new HashMap<>();
                                    JSONObject typ = jsonArrayFamille.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String type = typ.names().getString(0);
                                    JSONArray jsonArrayType = typ.getJSONArray(type);
                                    typeliste.add(type);
                                    for (int k = 0; k < jsonArrayType.length(); k++) {
                                        JSONObject mat = jsonArrayType.getJSONObject(k);
                                        ArrayList<MatosItem> outils = new ArrayList<>();
                                        String materiau = mat.names().getString(0);
                                        JSONArray jsonArraylistout = mat.getJSONArray(materiau);
                                        materiauliste.add(materiau);
                                        for (int l = 0; l < jsonArraylistout.length(); l++) {
                                            JSONObject out = jsonArraylistout.getJSONObject(l);
                                            String description = out.getString("description");
                                            String id = out.getString("id");
                                            String ref = out.getString("ref");
                                            String code_fourn = out.getString("code_fourn");
                                            Log.e("boucle",description+id);
                                            outils.add(new MatosItem(description, id, false, ref, code_fourn));
                                        }
                                        matItemList.put(materiau, outils);
                                    }
                                    typeItemList1.put(type, matItemList);
                                }
                                materielsItemList.put(famille, typeItemList1);
                                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(famille));

                            }
                            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

                             for (String i : Objects.requireNonNull(materielsItemList.get(famille1.get(0))).keySet()) {
                                list.add(i);
                                 Log.e(TAG, "run: "+i );
                            }

                            typeItemList = materielsItemList.get(famille1.get(0));
                            Log.e(TAG, "run: "+typeItemList );
                            matosListView.setAdapter(new MatosItemAdapter(context, typeItemList,list ));
                            tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                                    // get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                                    Fragment fragment = null;
                                    if (tab.isSelected()) {
                                        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                        for (String i : Objects.requireNonNull(materielsItemList.get(famille1.get(tab.getPosition()))).keySet()) {
                                            list.add(i);
                                        }
                                        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<MatosItem>>> typeItemList1 = new HashMap<>();
                                        typeItemList1 = materielsItemList.get(famille1.get(tab.getPosition()));
                                        matosListView.setAdapter(new MatosItemAdapter(context, typeItemList1, list));
                                    }

                                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                    ft.commit();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                                }
                            });
                            progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I checked the JSON
I tried to use a thread

```json
{
    "Outils" : [{
        "Soudeurs" : [
        {
            "Fils" : [
            {
                "Fil" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Fil MIG G3SI1 diam 1.2",
                    "id" : "26",
                    "ref" : "bobine de 15 kg",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Fourre OK1413 diam 1.2",
                    "id" : "45",
                    "ref" : "bobine 16 kg avec gaz",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "MIG inox 316L SI diam 1.2",
                    "id" : "46",
                    "ref" : "bobine 15 kg",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "Materiel de soudure" : [
            {
                "Gaine guide" : [
                {
                    "description" : "fil 25 x 45 4M diam 1.2",
                    "id" : "27",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }
            ]},
            {
                "Batterie" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Warrior AIR ESAB",
                    "id" : "47",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }
            ]},
            {
                "Cagoule" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Couvre nuque noire ESAB",
                    "id" : "48",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }
            ]},
            {
                "Protection" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Ecran de protection bleu",
                    "id" : "49",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Visiere transparente pour ecran HG930B",
                    "id" : "50",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Visiere teinte pour ecran HG930B",
                    "id" : "51",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }
            ]},
            {
                "Pince" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Stubby original 400 A",
                    "id" : "52",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Masse bronze GCB 450 A",
                    "id" : "53",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Masse bronze GCB 600 A",
                    "id" : "54",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "Electrodes" : [
            {
                "OK4627" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 2.5 x 350 rutile",
                    "id" : "25",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            },
            {
                "OK4800" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 2.5 x 350",
                    "id" : "32",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 3.2 x 350",
                    "id" : "33",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 4 x 350",
                    "id" : "34",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 5 x 450",
                    "id" : "35",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Inox 316 L 17" : [
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 2.5 x 300",
                    "id" : "36",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 3.2 x 350",
                    "id" : "37",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "Diam 4 x 350",
                    "id" : "38",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Gougeage" : [
                {
                    "description" : "6 x 305",
                    "id" : "39",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "8 x 305",
                    "id" : "40",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                },
                {
                    "description" : "10 x 305",
                    "id" : "41",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            },
            {
                "Nue" : [
                {
                    "description" : "9.5 x 914 slice",
                    "id" : "42",
                    "ref" : "x",
                    "code_fourn" : "x"
                }]
            }]
        }]},
        {
            "Ajusteurs" : [
            {
                "Accessoires" : [
                {
                    "Nettoyant" : [
                    {
                        "description" : "26.5 kg alfa marine",
                        "id" : "44",
                        "ref" : "x",
                        "code_fourn" : "x"
                    }]
                }]
            },
            {
                "Hydraulique" : [
                {
                    "Huile" : [
                    {
                        "description" : "Enerpac HF95Y bidon 5L",
                        "id" : "43",
                        "ref" : "x",
                        "code_fourn" : "x"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        },
        {
            "Machinistes" : [
            {
                "Accessoires" : [
                {
                    "Lame ebavureur" : [
                    {
                        "description" : "E100S (longue) boite de 10",
                        "id" : "30",
                        "ref" : "x",
                        "code_fourn" : "x"
                    },
                    {
                        "description" : "B10S (courte) boite de 10",
                        "id" : "31",
                        "ref" : "x",
                        "code_fourn" : "x"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }
```

I would like to have a correct display of the tools and their class. I don't have to have expandables list

Comment: The thread you use here `Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` is actually main (UI) thread itself. This may not arise a problem for a small set of data, however as the data gets bigger the more freezing in the UI might occur. Consider using a **background thread** instead.

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem clearly? It's hard to understand what the problem is from the images since they have only some markers and don't explain anything.

Comment: The images show that there are not the right items (here tools) in the lists. 
In the JSON we can see the increments, but when displayed in the expandable list the display is not good.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on my Handler. Would it be better to use an Async Task?

Comment: I would recommend you to use either [ExecutorService](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/asynchronous/java-threads#create-multiple) or [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) as a single threaded solution. `HandlerThread` is more Android OS specific hence can't be used in non-Android projects. In case of you don't know, you can't update UI elements from a background thread.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it
So in principle, I create my Hashmap containing my classification in background
Then I use it for my adapter